# In Ubuntu 12.04, odd whining/humming coming from left side of MBP (2,2)

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, macbook, cpu

I have been searching for a similar issue to mine, but unfortunately haven't found anything.

Anyhow, this week I installed 12.04 on my 2006 MBP (2,2). Pretty much everything seems to work OK, but shortly after getting to the log-in screen, an audible whining/humming begins from the left hand side of the laptop. The sound is faint, but you can definitely hear it. Phonetically, it sounds if you made a high-pitched "eeeeeee" sound. The sound is not constant, but persistent. It'll sound for just a second or two then go away, then come back for a time, then go away; almost like the long-short cadence of Morse Code.

The stranger thing is that upon plugging in headphones, the sound is amplified greatly. When removed, the sound goes back to being very quiet. The audio from the speakers or headphones isn't garbled as far as I can tell, so I don't know if this is a speaker issue. Maybe a grounding thing?

However, I feel like I have taken away hardware as an issue for the most part. I still have OS X on another partition, and the sound *never* occurs in OS X, only Ubuntu. My CPU temps in 12.04 sit idle around 60C, and they do in OS X as well. When running a program or watching a video, the fans come on as the CPU temps go up, but the increase in fan speed sounds uniform and normal. I have had a fan replaced in this laptop before, so I have an idea of what it sounds like when ball bearings get out of place.

I have tried turning down/off all sound related things in `alsamixer`, but that does't really do anything to stop the issue. I thought it might be a mic loop or something, but I have all sound off and the issue still stands. Maybe there's an internal speaker that is getting accessed that normally doesn't in OS X? I'm not sure.

Other than this sound, the OS works fine. I don't have any outstanding issues besides this one, weird thing.

So, I dunno (and if I did, I wouldn't be here, ha!). If anyone has an idea of something I might be able to check or amend, I'd be grateful to hear it.

Thanks!

**Edit:** As I sit here testing the machine, I have noticed that the sound does go away when you play audio through the headphone jack, but it comes back when not in use. My test was to play a song from Google Play using headphones, and the sound does go away but is replaced with intermittent "crunching" from...somewhere.

Weirdly, while in this state, moving the mouse via touchpad seems to cause the most occurrences of this "crunch"/static. There is a direct correlation for when I touch the pad to sound emitting from the machine, as though the power draw the pad takes when I touch it  is affecting...*something*.

Upon closing Chrome, the high pitched sound comes back shortly.

Removing the power supply does alter the sound a bit, but it is still present. Using solely battery power does not alleviate the issue, either.

**Edit 2:** I think I may have stumbled upon the answer to my question. Of course I would find it after I made this long post, but hopefully this post could help someone in the future.

[What worked (so far!) for me.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2027573&p=12109016#post12109016)

It turns out that some of the first generation MBPs had a whining problem due to whatever the C-State is, some state of being the CPU enters when idle. Due to a hardware glitch/bug, one C-State causes the computer to make a whining sound. So, what to do?

I give full credit to user [piwacet](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=955315) at the ubuntuforums, and this was their solution:

> In a terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo su
> nano -w /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> Change the line in this file that reads like this:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash processor.max_cstate=2"
> ```
>
> Save file (ctrl-x) execute:
>
> ```
> update-grub
> ```
>
> Then exit the terminal and reboot.

I have been listening to my MBP as I have been writing this, and I haven't heard anything abnormal like before. I can't guarantee that this is the best answer to this problem, but so far my computer is much quieter.

The only downside is that it seems like it is running just a little warmer. Before this (when the whine/hum would sound), the CPU would run about 60C. As I have sat here writing and listening, the CPU temp has been sitting around 66C. It jumped to 71C a couple of times. I have no programs running besides the temp indicators.